# InfluxDB SELECT query on multiple MEASUREMENT with different fieldType

Tags: select, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have an influxDB `testdb` where, I am trying a SELECT query on 4 different measurements with different `fieldtype`.I am able to query more than one measurements successfully but when it comes to combining multiple measurements with different `fieldType`, influxDB only returns results for one `fieldType`.

**Setup**

```
> create database testdb
> use testdb
Using database testdb
> insert rpm,path=P1 data=200
> insert rpm,path=P2 data=100
> insert rpm,path=P1 data=300
>
> insert load,path=P1 data=77
> insert load,path=P1 data=89
>
> insert mode,path=P1 data="AUTOMATIC"
> insert mode,path=P2 data="MANUAL"
> insert mode,path=P1 data="AUTOMATIC"
>
> insert execution,path=P1 data="ACTIVE"
```

Now I have 4 measurements namely, `rpm`, `load`, `mode`, `execution`. Their `fieldType` are:

```
> show field keys on testdb
name: execution
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
data     string

name: load
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
data     float

name: mode
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
data     string

name: rpm
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
data     float
```

**What I can do**

I am able to get results successfully from more than one measurements of same `fieldType`.

```
> select last(data) from mode, execution
name: execution
time                last
----                ----
1564000155710480300 ACTIVE

name: mode
time                last
----                ----
1564000155694460700 AUTOMATIC
>
> select last(data) from rpm, load
name: load
time                last
----                ----
1564000155650446100 89

name: rpm
time                last
----                ----
1564000155620293100 300
```

**Problem**

I am not able to combine all 4 measurements into one single query. the below query should return results for all 4 measurements, instead it returns results for only `float` type.

```
> select last(data) from mode, execution, rpm, load
name: load
time                last
----                ----
1564000155650446100 89

name: rpm
time                last
----                ----
1564000155620293100 300
```

If I change the order, I get the same result:

```
> select last(data) from rpm, load, mode, execution
name: load
time                last
----                ----
1564000155650446100 89

name: rpm
time                last
----                ----
1564000155620293100 300
```

Is there a way so that I can get the result for `string` and `float` type in one result set?

Comment: Hi @harvpan, did you got any work around for it ? for moment now I'm facing  similar situation as yours. Cheers

Comment: @khmub the only solution that i found through influxdb community website is to have two separate queries for different fieldtypes.